# How exactly do mapped fields in elastic search work?

Tags: elasticsearch

[The documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-fields.html) is sparse and not entirely helpful. So say I have the following fields for my attribute:

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "my_type": {
        "my_attribute": {
          "mapping": {
            "my_attribute": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
              "fields": {
                "lowercased": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "raw": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`my_analyzer` lowercases tokens (in addition to other stuff).

So now I would like to know if the following statements are true:

1. `my_analyzer` does not get applied to `raw`, because the `not_analyzed` index does not have any analyzers, as its name implies.
2. `my_attribute` and `my_attribute.lowercased` are the exact same, so it is redundant to have the field `my_attribute.lowercased`

Comment: your statements are correct for both 1 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first statement is correct, however the second is not. `my_attribute` and `my_attribute.lowercased` might not be the same since the former has your **custom** `my_analyzer` search and index analyzer, while `my_attribute.lowercased` has the [`standard` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) (since no analyzer is specified the standard one kicks in).

Besides, your mapping is not correct the way it is written, it should be like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "my_attribute": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
          "fields": {
            "lowercased": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```